# Difference between "did save" and "saved"

Tags: difference, past-simple

What is the *difference* between the two following sentences?

> 1) Where **did** you **save** that file?

And

> 2) Where you **saved** that file ?

Comment: I think the first one is correct and grammatical but the second one is not.

Comment: Indeed, the distinction between the two sentences is that the second one is produced only by non-native speakers.  The exception would be in an exchange such as the following: Person A: "What was it that you wanted to know?"; Person B: "Where you saved that file."  But here, "where you saved that file" might be better regarded as a sentence fragment.

Comment: @rjpond I have heard native speakers produce sentences like the second one, but very rarely. Also their speech would not sound educated to most people. But I have heard it. Everytime I have heard it it was spoken by a people from an urban ghetto.

Answer (score 7):

Let's imagine that your friend saved a file somewhere, and you wanted to know where it had been saved. You would ask:

*"Where did you save that file?"*

Afterwards you might say to your friend:

*"I wondered where you saved that file."*

If you are asking the question, you cannot say:

*"Where you saved that file?"*

It's incorrect.

But you can use those words as part of a sentence, as illustrated.

http://www.grammar.cl/english/do-does-did-done.htm
https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/en/grammar/frage5.htm

Answer (score 1):

In short the difference is the function of the word "where". In the first sentence is used as [adverb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/adverb), and in the second is used as [conjunction](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conjunction).

Explanation:

The correct *formal* structure of questions ([interrogative sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative)) of the past simple tense is:

> *auxiliary verb ➕ pronoun ➕ infinitive verb*

and with Wh questions is:

> *Wh question (adverb) ➕ auxiliary verb ➕ pronoun ➕ infinitive verb*

Therefore, the the **correct *formal* interrogative sentence** is:

> *Where **did** you **save** that file?*

---

On the other hand, you can use in a **statement** (declarative sentence) that says:

> I am not sure **where** you saved that file.

In this case, the word "**where**" is not used as wh question (=adverb) but as conjunction.

So in the end of the day, both are correct depending on the context.

Obviously, it is not possible to **ask**:

> **Where** you saved that file? ❎